# LXML: Is it possible to search within an element?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm used to Beautifulsoup where I would extract elements and then search within them. But LXML doesn't see to behave that way and looks like it is searching from the main document.

From the following example, the output I get is:

Case:  1

- Criteria:  1
- Criteria:  2
- Criteria:  3
- Criteria:  4

Case:  2

- Criteria:  1
- Criteria:  2
- Criteria:  3
- Criteria:  4

but what I expected was:

Case:  1

- Criteria:  1
- Criteria:  2

Case:  2

- Criteria:  3
- Criteria:  4

Sample code:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring

html = """
<p>Test document</p>
<case id='1'>
  <criteria id='1'><p>Some text</p></criteria>
  <criteria id='2'><p>Some more text</p></criteria>
</case>
<case id='2'>
  <criteria id='3'><p>It just keeps going</p></criteria>
  <criteria id='4'><p>Will it never end?</p></criteria>
</case>
"""

doc = fromstring(html)
case_list = doc.xpath('//case')
for case in case_list:
    print('Case: ', case.get('id'))
    criteria_list = case.xpath('//criteria')
    for criteria in criteria_list:
        print(' - Criteria: ', criteria.get('id'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably in this line:

```
criteria_list = case.xpath('//criteria')
```

Try to replace XPath expression from '//criteria' (which searches document from the root) to './criteria' (which searches from current element):

```
criteria_list = case.xpath('./criteria')
```